# How to make PgAdmin port maping for Nginx reverse proxy config

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx

I've several Docker containers running on an AWS EC2 instance, the containers info is:

```
0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, :::443->443/tcp   ningx_ctnr
443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5050->80/tcp, :::5050->80/tcp                             pgadmin_ctnr
4000/tcp, 9000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp              django_ctnr
...
```

And the Security Group for the instance has inbound rules for 80 and 443 ports.

The Nginx config files are:

django.conf:

```
upstream django_app {
  server  ec2_private_IP:8000;
}
server {
  listen  80;
  listen  [::]:80;
  server_name   *.stage.my_domain.es stage.my_domain.es;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen  443 ssl;
  listen  [::]:443 ssl;
  server_name   *.stage.my_domain.es stage.my_domain.es;
  ...
  certs and log info
  ... 
  location / {
    ...
    headers info
    ... 
    proxy_redirect  off;
    proxy_pass      http://django_app;
  }
}
```

pgadmin.conf:

```
upstream pgadmin_app {
  server  ec2_private_IP:80;
}
server {
  listen  80;
  listen  [::]:80;
  server_name   *.pgadmin.stage.my_domain.es pgadmin.stage.my_domain.es;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen  443 ssl;
  listen  [::]:443 ssl;
  server_name   *.pgadmin.stage.my_domain.es pgadmin.stage.my_domain.es;
  ...
  certs and log info
  ... 
  location / {
    ...
    headers info
    ... 
    proxy_redirect  off;
    proxy_pass      http://pgadmin_app;
  }
}
```

The problem is accessing https://stage.my_domain.es works well and reverse to the Django project but accessing https://pgadmin.stage.my_domain.es reverse to Django again.

UPDATE

Locally I've tried to change PgAdmin listen port env var to 8001

```
PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=8001
```

And the result container shows:

```
80/tcp, 443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8001->8001/tcp                                  elitecars_local_pgadmin_ctnr
```

And try to change Nginx config files

django.conf:

```
upstream django_app {
  server  pgadmin:8001;
}
server {
  listen  80;
  listen  [::]:80;
  server_name   localhost;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  ...
```

pgadmin.conf:

```
upstream pgadmin_app {
  server  django:8000;
}
server {
  listen  80;
  listen  [::]:80;
  server_name   pgadmin.localhost;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  ...
```

Accessing http://localhost works well and reverse to the PgAdmin project but accessing http://pgadmin.localhost no so I deduce that it may be a problem with the subdomain and the server_name.

Adding to vhosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost pgadmin.localhost *.localhost
...
```

Still not working.

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry my fault, reviewing the container logs on EC2 I’ve seen that PgAdmin user didn’t have permission for write logs on default /var/lib/pgadmin path. Solved setting SESSION_DB_PATH env var to /home/pgadmin